# How can I make the subview clip to the bounds of the UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I have a UIView which is the `MapViewController` and a subview of the Google Maps which is `googleMapsView` I am wondering how I can make it so that the Google Maps clips to the bounds of the MapViewController. I tried to do a `clipToBounds = true` but it is not working. I probably am doing something wrong though. If someone would help me out I would be very grateful. Thank you.

```
@IBOutlet weak var MapViewContainer: UIView!

var googleMapsView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView(frame: self.MapViewContainer.frame)
self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)
view.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: you want to corner radius MapViewContainer

Comment: @Sh_Khan how would I do that?

Comment: try self.MapViewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 10

Comment: you should add  googleMapsView  to MapViewContainer not to self.view

Comment: view.layer.maskToBounds maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a handle on how views, subviews, bounds, frame, and clipping work. You have:

```
self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView(frame: self.MapViewContainer.frame)
self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)
view.clipsToBounds = true
```

You should say:

```
self.googleMapsView = GMSMapView(frame: self.MapViewContainer.bounds)
self.MapViewContainer.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)
self.MapViewContainer.clipsToBounds = true
```